# Joda Period in year month day

Tags: java, jodatime

i am using following code to get difference between 2 dates in year,month,day

```
tenAppDTO.getTAP_PROPOSED_START_DATE()=2009-11-01  
tenAppDTO.getTAP_PROPOSED_END_DATE()=2013-11-29                                                                         
ReadableInstant r=new DateTime(tenAppDTO.getTAP_PROPOSED_START_DATE());
ReadableInstant r1=new DateTime(tenAppDTO.getTAP_PROPOSED_END_DATE());
Period period = new Period(r, r1);  
period.normalizedStandard(PeriodType.yearMonthDay());
years =  period.getYears();
month=period.getMonths();
day=period.getDays();   
out.println("year is-:"+years+"month is -:"+ month+"days is -:"+ day);
```

by using above code i get the result year is-:4 month is -:0 days is -:0 
but actual result is year is-:4 month is -:0 days is -:28

Please provide a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You  may try to change

```
Period period = new Period(r, r1);
```

with

```
Period period = new Period(r, r1, PeriodType.yearMonthDay());
```

You may try like this:

```
tenAppDTO.getTAP_PROPOSED_START_DATE()=2009-11-01  
tenAppDTO.getTAP_PROPOSED_END_DATE()=2013-11-29                                                                         
ReadableInstant r=new DateTime(tenAppDTO.getTAP_PROPOSED_START_DATE());
ReadableInstant r1=new DateTime(tenAppDTO.getTAP_PROPOSED_END_DATE());
Period period = new Period(r, r1, PeriodType.yearMonthDay());   //Change here  
period.normalizedStandard(PeriodType.yearMonthDay());
years =  period.getYears();
month=period.getMonths();
day=period.getDays();   
out.println("year is-:"+years+"month is -:"+ month+"days is -:"+ day);
```

Comment: @RahulTripathi Can you please explain how **new Period(r, r1, day);** worked? why do we need to include day in it?

Comment: @Octopus:- Is that wrong? I mean I didnt get you very clearly. May be I should have written this:- Period period = new Period(date1, date2, PeriodType.yearMonthDay());

Answer (score 0):

Even thou Rahul already answered, I can provide a bit more visually appealing code (as both the question and the answer are a bit messy):

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2009, 11, 01, 00, 00);
DateTime date2 = new DateTime(2013, 11, 29, 00, 00);
Period period = new Period(date1, date2, PeriodType.yearMonthDay());
System.out.println("Y: " + period.getYears() + ", M: " + period.getMonths() +
        ", D: " + period.getDays());
// => Y: 4, M: 0, D: 28
```

You need to specify period type as *year-month-day* as the standard type (`PeriodType.standard()`) is based on *year-month-**week**-day-...* and the day difference for the specified dates is exactly **4 weeks**:

```
Period period = new Period(date1, date2, PeriodType.standard());
System.out.println("Y: " + period.getYears() + ", M: " + period.getMonths() +
        ", W: " + period.getWeeks() + ", D: " + period.getDays());
// => Y: 4, M: 0, W: 4, D: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Period.of` from `java.time.Period`

```
public Period getPeriodForMonthsAndDays(int monthsCount, int daysCount) {
    return Period.of(0, monthsCount, daysCount);
}
```